# Eclipse 3.x: Toggle Button for one instance of a Editor View

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I have an issue with a toggle button for a editorPage. It seems that this button is not view specific. If the button is toggled in one view, it is toggled in all views. How can I archive a view specific toggle button?

```
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <command
            id="de.sni.de.editor.extensions.editWithResolvedTopics"
            name="%editWithResolvedTopicsToolbarName">
         <state
               class="org.eclipse.ui.handlers.RegistryToggleState:false"
               id="org.eclipse.ui.commands.toggleState">
         </state>
      </command>
   </extension>
```

```
    private void addOpenWithResolvedTopicsButtons(ToolBarManager toolBarManager) {
        IWorkbench wb = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
        IWorkbenchWindow win = wb.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();

        Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("de.sni.de.editor.extensions");//$NON-NLS-1$
        URL fullPathString = bundle.getEntry("icons/OpenInEditorResolvedTopics16.png");
        ImageDescriptor icon = ImageDescriptor.createFromURL(fullPathString);

        CommandContributionItemParameter openWithResolvedTopics = new CommandContributionItemParameter(win,
                "OpenWWoResolvedTopics", // $NON-NLS-1$
                "de.sni.de.editor.extensions.editWithResolvedTopics", null, icon, icon, icon,
                "Resolve Topics", "", "", SWT.CHECK, "", false);//$NON-NLS-1$//$NON-NLS-2$//$NON-NLS-3$//$NON-NLS-4$

        CommandContributionItem openWithResolvedTopicsContributionItem = new CommandContributionItem(
                openWithResolvedTopics);
        toolBarManager.add(openWithResolvedTopicsContributionItem);

    }
```

Seems to be globally evaluated, so that one toggle in one view toggles all views.

Thanks for your help :)

Best regards
Sven

Comment: As you found command state is global, you can't use that. If you aren't using the org.eclipse.ui.menus extension point to define the tool bar item with an enabledWnen you will probably have to override the AbstractHandler `isEnabled` method in the handler for the command.